# Sorting a listbox containing grid controls in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am writing an app that will display several thumbnails of jpegs with the filename underneath them.  I would like to sort these by filename.  These jpegs are coming out of a zip file and I cannot receive them in sorted order.  I'm using a listbox defined like this:

```
   <ListBox Name="listPanel1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Name="wrapPanel1" IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <TextBox Height="152" Name="tb_Messages" Width="244" />
    </ListBox>
```

Then in the code I add an individual grid control for each thumbnail to the listPanel.  The first row of the grid is the image, the second is the filename.

```
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        ColumnDefinition col0 = new ColumnDefinition();
        RowDefinition row0 = new RowDefinition();
        RowDefinition row1 = new RowDefinition();
        col0.Width = new GridLength(140);
        row0.Height = new GridLength(140);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col0);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row0);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row1);
        grid.Children.Add(thumbnailImage);
        grid.Children.Add(lb);
        Grid.SetRow(thumbnailImage, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(thumbnailImage, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(fileName, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(fileName, 0);
        listPanel1.Items.Add(grid);
```

One of the nice things about this method is that when I select an image both the image and the filename are highlighted.

How can I sort the listbox based on the filename?

This is my first WPF app, so it's entirely possibly that I'm approaching this in the completely wrong way.

Comment: The approach would be to read all the files into a list, sort the list and insert them into into the listPanel.  I have no experience that tells if you are doing the right thing with the WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create the UI in code! Unless you are creating an user control.

1. Use a `ListBox` and bind it datasource to collection of the objects representing the picture

   ```
   <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Pictures}"/>
   ```
2. In your view model you will get the names and other properties and `Pictures` property will return sorted collection (or filtered or whatever)

   ```
   public IEnumerable<Picture> Pictures
   {
      get { return _picturesLoadedFromZip.OrderBy(whatever); }
   }
   ```
3. To display the thumbnail and file name use [template](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/resources/644/how-to-display-images-in-a-wpf-listbox.aspx).

   ```
   <ListBoxItem Background="LightCoral" Foreground="Red" 
        FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"> 
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
         <Image Source="{Binding PathToFile}" Height="30"></Image>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"></TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
   </ListBoxItem>
   ```

More about this you can find [here](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/ListBoxes-with-DataBound-Images-in-WPF.aspx) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18561/Custom-ListBox-Layout-in-WPF).

Comment: Thanks Karel, those links and your example provide some useful information.  I'll give this a try later on and see if it works for me.  The one concern I have is that I'm filling the listbox one item at a time as the pictures are unarchived via a callback mechanism.  And I would like the display to reflect that so the user has some idea what is happening.  They could resort each time an image is added, or I could sort at the end of the process, either way works for me.

Comment: Do you have to do something to invoke the sort?  I've implemented the template and made a class for thumbnails that implements IEnumerated but I still see it in the order in which I add things.

Comment: Got it. Added  `listPanel1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("_fileName", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending) );` when extraction finished and the listbox items are then sorted.